# How does adding acids (H+ ions) to limited soluble salts help it further dissolve?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution

For example, adding $\ce{HCl}$ to the very insoluble $\ce{CaF2}$ will help it further dissolve. How?

I believe the concept deals with equilibrium and Le Chatelier's Principle:

$$ \ce{ CaF2 <=> Ca^2+ + 2F^-} $$

Does adding $\ce{H+}$ react with the $\ce{F-}$, which shifts the equilibrium to the right-hand side and therefore further dissolve the salt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the solubility of a sparingly soluble salt having a basic anion will increase with the addition of a strong acid.  Given:

$$\ce{X+A- <--> X+ + A-}$$

where $K_{sp}$ is small and A- is a weak base, the addition of a strong acid will form HA, driving the reaction to the right and increasing $K_{sp}$.

In the specific case of

$$\ce{CaF2 <--> Ca^2+ + 2F−}$$

the addition of $\ce{HCl}$ gives

$$\ce{CaF2 + 2HCl <--> Ca^2+ + 2Cl- +2HF}$$

driving the reaction to the right, thus increasing the solubility of $\ce{CaF2}$.  Note that $\ce{HF}$ itself is a weak acid, having a pKa of $3.17$, and will be in equilibrium with $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{F-}$.